# How do I insert a folder into a ZIP file?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

I'm a newbie on Linux and had to do something like this with the zip command:

My folder structure inside a zip file abc.zip is:

```
-- currentdir
  -- onestepdeep
     -- abc.zip
       -- folder1
         -- textfile.txt
       -- folder2
  -- seconddir
    -- folder3 
      -- textfile.txt
```

I need to copy the file `textfile.txt` from the `seconddir/folder3` into `folder1` inside `abc.zip`

I could move `textfile.txt` into `abc.zip` with the following outcomes:

1. It would move into `abc.zip` as `folder3/textfile.txt` (the hierarchy preserved)
2. Also used a `-j` switch (help said it junked the path info and it did but) - it would move only into `abc.zip` and sit at the same level as `folder1` and `folder2` instead of replacing the `textfile.txt` within `abc.zip/folder1`

My question is - I want to replace the `abc.zip/folder1/textfile.txt` with the one inside `seconddir/folder3/textfile.txt`.

How do I achieve this via the command line interface?

Answer (score 2):

I also use tar, but if you require zip then:

`zip -b path/to/create/in zipfile.zip textfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I always roll with tar myself...

```
tar -cjf destination_archive_file.tar.bz2 /path/to/directory/to/archive
```

That would give ya a file 'destination_archive_file.tar.bz2' with all the contents within '/path/to/directory/to/archive' stored in it.

Then to extract, you just use:

```
tar -xjvf destination_archive_file.tar.bz2
```

Anyway, I know you blatantly asked for zip, not tar. I've tried zip a few times and found it to be a little counter-intuitive. Never did bother to really figure it out since I'd just use tar and get on with it. If you need to extrat a tar in Windows, [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) or [winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) should do the trick. I'm pretty sure OSX supports it natively.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe install `fuse-zip`, which is a very convenient tool. The following command:

```
fuse-zip abc.zip abc.mnt
```

will show the content of `abc.zip` in an `abc.mnt` directory. Then do whatever you want with the content of the directory:

```
cp -r ../seconddir/folder3 abc.mnt/
```

After that, unmount the directory:

```
fusermount -u abc.mnt; rm -rf abc.mnt
```

You're done.

Comment: It was really simple and it worked.